# Pagination algorithm with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I have a javascript function which makes an ajax request to php controller method which returns a JSON encoded array.

```
function initGallery(offset) {
        if(offset === undefined)
        {
        var request_url = url+'avatar/gallery';
        } else {
        var request_url = url+'avatar/gallery/'+offset;
        }
        $('#avatar_gallery').html('')
        $.get(request_url,function(data) {
            var dat = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            //Build gallery
            $('#avatar_gallery').html('<div class="gallery_box"></div>');
            $('.gallery_box').append('<div class="gallery_header">Your Avatar Gallery</div>');
            $('.gallery_box').append('<div class="gallery_container"></div>');
            $.each(dat.avatars,function(index,item)
            {
                $('.gallery_container').append(
                    '<div class="gallery_item">'+
                    '<img src="'+item.avatar_src+'" id="'+item.avatar_id+'" onclick="avatar.view_avatar(this.id)"/>'+
                    '</div>'
                );
            });
                $('.gallery_box').append('<div class="gallery_footer"></div>');
                $('.gallery_footer').html('<div class="gallery_pagination"><div>');
        });
    }
```

And this is my controller method

```
function gallery($offset= 0)
    {
        $limit = 12;
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $data = $this->avatar_model->user_avatars($user_id,$limit,$offset);
        $avatars = array();
        $count = $this->avatar_model->count_user_avatars($user_id);
        $pages = ceil($count/$limit);

        foreach($data as $key => $avatar)
        {
            $dat['avatar_id'] = $avatar->avatar_id;
            $dat['avatar_src'] = $avatar->avatar_small;
            $dat['create_date'] = time("d-m-Y",$avatar->create_date);
            $avatars[] = $dat;
        }

        $server_response['avatar_count'] = $count;
        $server_response['avatars'] = $avatars;

        echo json_encode($server_response);
    }
```

I dont really have an idea on how to paginate the data returned from the reques.
Please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. Add a class to your pagination link (you can use `full_tag_open` and `full_tag_close` config variable: `<p class="pagination>` and `</p>`).
After that you can redefine the `.pagination a` click event (I'm using JQuery):

```
function () {
    $(".pagination a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        YourJSFunction($(this).attr("href"));
    });
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: tried your suggestion, but it doesnt seem to be working,the links still behave the default way